# typewriter effect to keyboard stroke

Tags: keyboard, audio

Is there any way to add (sound) typewriter effect to keyboard stroke?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here](http://www.ehow.com/how_4521694_noises-every-time-press-key.html) is a link to an article that explains how to do this natively (without any 3rd party applications).

And [here](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/12077/typewriter-keyboard) is an app - Typewriter Keyboard - that makes it sound authentically like a typewriter.

Hope this helps.